# Why can't I add more options to the search in Finder?

Tags: finder, search

I used to be able to click on the + next to save. After I upgraded to Yosemite, the + now became a - and I can't add exact match anymore. Any idea?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start your Search from anywhere else except "All My Files"

I don't know why, but that has no +
possibly because it's already a smart list, under the skin

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but it's because you are searching from the "all my files" view. Try clicking another folder and then initiating a search.